# Регулярка для тестовых смайлов типа wink

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, собрать регулярку для отлавливания следующих текстовых смайлов:

;-), ;), ;-D, ;D, (;, (-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если набор небольшой и ограничен, проще всего перечислить через ИЛИ (только нужно экранировать спецсимволы, в вашем случае скобки):

```
;-\)|;\)|;-D|;D|\(;|\(-;
```

Comment: И правда. Спасибо ) Че-то подумал, что нужно воротить что-то сложное